# What's the difference between $?CLASS and ::?CLASS

Tags: raku, compile-time, compile-time-constant, rakudo

The Raku docs [describe](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Compile-time_variables) `::?CLASS` as a compile-time variable that answers "Which class am I in?".  Then, [a couple of paragraphs later](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Introspection_compile-time_variables), it mentions `$?CLASS`, and says that it answers "Which class am I in? (as variable)".

What's the difference between these two variables?  They *often* seem to contain the same value – do they always?  Or are there differences I haven't observed?

Comment: Try doing `class A { method foo($?CLASS:D:) { } }`  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two forms of [compile-time variables](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Compile-time_variables) are different *syntactically*.

The syntactic form `::?foo` may be used as, and will be evaluated as:

- A [term](https://docs.raku.org/language/terms) (just like a variable such as `$?foo`).
- A [type constraint](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-type_constraint) (*unlike* a variable such as `$?foo`).